# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin(m\theta_k)(\pi-\theta_k)$

Tags: summation

In the process to compute $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{m-1}}{1+t^{2n}}{\rm d}t$ (see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471951/problem-with-the-integral-int-0-infty-fractm-11t2n-rm-dt/4472278#4472278)), I got stuck on this sum :
$$S_{m,n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin(m\theta_k)(\pi-\theta_k)$$
where $m$ and $n$ are integers, $1\le m<2n$, and $\theta_k=\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}$.

Knowing the result, I tried to multiply this sum by $\sin\frac{m\pi}{2n}$ to get a telescopic form, but I got stuck on something horrible, like this :
$$\frac{1}{2n}\left[\pi-\theta_0 -\frac\pi n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cos\frac{mk\pi}{n} + \cos(m\pi)(\pi-\theta_{n-1})\right]$$
and I don't know what to do, because the sum in the middle does only "simplifies" in
$$\frac12\frac{(-1)^{m+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{2m}-1}{\sin\frac{m\pi}{2n}}$$
if I'm not mistaken (I should be !).

Do you see anything simpler than what I did ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left(m\frac{\pi  (2 k+1) }{2
   n}\right)\left(\pi -\frac{\pi  (2 k+1)}{2 n}\right)$$ Before any simplification (given by a CAS)
$$S_{m,n}=\frac{2 \pi  n \csc \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2 n}\right)-\pi  \sin \left(\frac{\pi  m
   (2 n+1)}{2 n}\right) \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  m}{2 n}\right)-\pi  \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 \pi  m-\pi )\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2
   n}\right)}{4 n}$$ After simplification (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28Pi+-+%28%281+%2B+2*k%29*Pi%29%2F%282*n%29%29*Sin%5B%28%281+%2B+2*k%29*m*Pi%29%2F%282*n%29%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D))
$$S_{m,n}=\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2 n}\right) \left(2 n-\sin (\pi  m) \cot
   \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2 n}\right)\right)}{4 n}$$ Since $m$ is an integer
$$S_{m,n}=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2 n}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$S_{m, n}$ is just the imaginary part of $\sum e^{im\theta_k}(\pi -\theta_k)$.

$\sum e^{im\theta_k}$ is just a geometric series, so a closed form is available.

As for $\sum e^{im \theta_k} \theta_k$, note that it's closely related to the derivative of $\sum e^{im \theta_k}$ with respect to $m$.